# Adding item to an associative array in php at index 0

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id=1");
print_r($result);
```

Here is the result data from mysql query.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => "John"
            [middleinitial] => "A."
            [lastname] => "Doe"
        )
)
```

I want to add address: "USA" after the lastname that will result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => "John"
            [middleinitial] => "A."
            [lastname] => "Doe"
            [address] => "USA"
        )
)
```

How can I append that to `$result` variable in php? Help would much appreciated. Tnx :)

Comment: try with $result[0]->address = 'USA';

Comment: Or `SELECT *,'USA' as address FROM users where id=1` Then it will be in the array without needing to add it

Comment: Or better still amend the table to have a column to hold that data

Comment: tnx @AlfredoEM. It works

Answer (score 2):

This will work in one/more than one element case

```
$result = array_map(function ($v) {
    $v->address = "USA";
    return $v;
}, $result);
```

Give it a try. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
  $result[0]->address = "USA";
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a property to the object contained in the first index of your array,

```
$result[0]->address = 'USA';
```

Furthermore, if your array has multiple indices and you want to iterate through them all and add an address then you can do the following:

```
foreach ($result as &$row) {
    $row->address = 'USA';
}
```

where the `&` is to pass the `$row` variable into the loop by reference so that you can modify it.